# Showing a album cover

Tags: spotify

I was wondering how to add a album cover on my spotify-app?

With this code I can reveal the album title, but how can I show the album cover!?

```
function updatePageWithAlbumName() {

var header = document.getElementById("album");

// This will be null if nothing is playing.
var playerTrackInfo = sp.trackPlayer.getNowPlayingTrack();

if (playerTrackInfo == null) {
    header.innerText = "Geen album!";
} else {
    var track = playerTrackInfo.track;
    header.innerText = track.album.name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use any of the `sp.` APIs - they're private and going away soon.

The public API is documented here: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/preview/reference/

You can show an album cover like this:

```
<img src="[cover URI]">
```

Edit: To get the cover URI of the current track:

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');

var currentTrackCoverUri = models.player.track.album.cover;
```

Comment: But how can I find the cover URI / how to place it? I checked this link: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/preview/reference/4c26b7e8e0.html 
They also have a example on the page, but how can I see the album cover from the song that I'm playing?

Comment: And what do I need to use instead of the 'sp'? In the developer link they are also using the 'sp'.

Comment: They're using sp.require to get the model objects, then that's it. Everything else should be using the models and views objects. I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I still dont know how to pop it up.
Do I need to place the <img src=""> @ the index.html?
Or do you need to do that in the .js file?

Got the following lines in my .js file:
    var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
    var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
    exports.init = init;
    function init() {
        var currentTrackCoverUri = models.player.track.album.cover;
        ........
    }

What am I missing?

Comment: This is now way beyond the scope of this question - have a look for a tutorial on inserting text into HTML using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that the property seems to be called "image" and not "cover".
So the snippet provided by iKenndac would be rewritten as

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
var currentTrackCoverUri = models.player.track.album.image;
```

Not sure if this is dependant on my Spotify version, I'm running 0.8.10.3.g07d01e81.

Answer (score 0):

The UX guidelines requires you to present an album cover with playability when appropriate. This can be done with the solution from another topic: [Views.player album cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547337/views-player-album-cover)

Comment: Dear pompa, thanks your comment helped me very well. With that solution it shows a album cover of skrillex, can you give me a direction on how to show the 'now-playing album cover'?

Comment: You can bring out that information from the models~player object. 

var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
models.Player.track.album

Remember to use the Player observe listener to you see when a track changes: models.EVENT.CHANGE