# Views.player album cover

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to set a custom image on the views.player?
I've tried to change the player.image.node but I don't get it to work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'm doing. Not sure if it is the official way but it works.

```
var player = new views.Player();
var image = new views.Image(img_url, spotify_uri, title);
$(player.node).find('.sp-player-image').replaceWith(image.node);
$('.player_div').append(player.node);
```

I would love to hear if anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the documentation about the views are quite undocumented.

Here's how you use the view to generate the album widget.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sp://import/css/eve.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sp://import/css/api.css">
</head>

<div id="album-element"></div>
<script>
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var views = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/views');
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');

models.Album.fromURI('spotify:album:6HbNEBza64W10MQxUFq6QL', function(album) { 
    var p = new views.Player(); 
    p.context = album; 
    document.getElementById('album-element').appendChild(p.node); 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```