# Retrieving album/playlist information API

Tags: spotify

I read in another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474011/showing-a-album-cover)
that the:

> Please don't use any of the sp. APIs - they're private and going away soon.

My question is, what is the correct way of getting album and/or playlist information from the API?

I'm currently playing around with this:

```
sp.core.getMetadata(uri, {
    onSuccess: function(uri) {
       // Success
    },
    onFailure: function() {
       // Failure
    }
});
```

I guess this is private and shouldn't be used right? Instead I should get the info from the models.* object? If not, is there another preferred method of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use models. Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/).

For example:

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');

var a = models.Album.fromURI("spotify:album:5zyS3GEyL1FmDWgVXxUvj7", function(album) {
    console.log("Album loaded", album.name);
});
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote or mark my answer as the correct answer (or both!) ;-)

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I don't usually post here, so not familiar with all the stuff atm. :)